# MKMapView -> to UIImage -> to NSData

Tags: iphone, uiimage, nsdata, mkmapview

for a MKMapView : UIView

how could i convert the content of the mkmapview to a uiimage?

although from the mkmapview the end goal (or *primary main objective*, if you know what i mean) is a NSData var which I can then attach to an email with mimeType "image/png"

kinda of grabbing a screenshot of whatever the MKMapview is showing at any given moment

putting that on a (UIImage)mapImage

NSData *imageData= UIImagePNGRepresentation(mapImage);

any tips?

thanks in advance

Comment: Just a word of caution. Be very careful what you do with that content you grab from the displayed map. Googles license terms limit what you may do with it: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/terms.html#section_10_1_3

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Why not try something like this (untested)?

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(mapView.frame.size);
[mapView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *mapImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

NSData *mapData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(mapImage);
[mapData writeToFile:[self myFilePath:@"yourMap.png"] atomically:YES];
```

Comment: Here is one of those instances where I wish I could upvote something twice.